# grep a block of lines into a shell variable based on matching pattern

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, sed

I'm looking for a way to grep the block of lines between {} based on given pattern.I tried various patterns i found in google but none of them are helping my case.i'm not pro in regex.looking for some help to tackle this problem.
This is the sample source file:

```
Data {
        status 400;
        server_name test.dummy.com;

        location /test {
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_read_timeout 5m;
proxy_send_timeout 5m;
proxy_pass http://xyz.9201.com;

               proxy_http_version 1.1;
               proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
               proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }

        location /dev {
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_read_timeout 5m;
proxy_send_timeout 5m;
proxy_pass http://xyz.9202.com;

               proxy_http_version 1.1;
               proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
               proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }

        location /prd {
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_read_timeout 5m;
proxy_send_timeout 5m;
proxy_pass http://xyz.9203.com;

               proxy_http_version 1.1;
               proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
               proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
}
```

if the argument passed to the script is "dev" , then it should match the pattern **location** /dev and extract below block into a shell variable:

location /dev {

> ```
> proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
> proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
> proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
> proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
> proxy_read_timeout 5m;
> proxy_send_timeout 5m;
> proxy_pass http://xyz.9202.com;
>                proxy_http_version 1.1;
>                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
>                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
> ```

i tried various sed/awk command patterns but this one below is giving me some nearest result.

```
awk '/dev/{print}' RS={ FS=} test.conf
```

result:

```
$ awk '/dev/{print}' RS={ FS=} test.txt

proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_read_timeout 5m;
proxy_send_timeout 5m;
proxy_pass http://xyz.9201.com;

               proxy_http_version 1.1;
               proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
               proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }

        location /dev
```

Comment: On SO we do encourage people to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, could you please do add same in your question and let us know then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could do it in a single `awk` itself, could you please try following.

```
awk '/}/ && found{exit} /location \/dev/{found=1;next} found && NF' Input_file
```

Since OP mentioned that only 1st set should be printed so I am using `exit` here to exit immediately once fist set it printed.

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code.

```
awk '                   ##Starting awk program from here.
/}/ && found{           ##Checking condition if a line contains } AND variable found is SET then do following.
  exit                  ##Exiting from program here.
}                       ##Closing BLOCK for above condition here.
/location \/dev/{       ##Checking condition here if a line contains location /dev then do following.
  found=1               ##Setting variable found to 1 here.   
  next                  ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}                       ##Closing BLOCK for above condition here.
found && NF             ##Checking condition is  found is SET and NF is NOT NULL then print current line.
' Input_file            ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Output will be as follows.

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host ;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server ;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For ;
proxy_set_header Host ;
proxy_read_timeout 5m;
proxy_send_timeout 5m;
proxy_pass http://xyz.9202.com;
               proxy_http_version 1.1;
               proxy_set_header Upgrade ;
               proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
```

Comment: it works. but its not strictly matching the pattern( i agree i should have been more specific). if i add one more stanza to the file with /dev2. its giving two results.

Comment: @ramesh.metta, After first stanza is printing I am simply coming out of program which will be very FASTER and will save your time too.

Comment: Really well explained awk ++

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 what can i change here to look for :  `location /AuditManagement/ { `

Comment: @ramesh.metta, Sure, change `/location \/dev/ ` with `/location \/AuditManagement\/ {/`  and it should fly then.

Comment: i tried below: i replaced ' with " because i have to use a variable instead of hard code string "AuditManagement". output=$(awk "/}/ && found{exit} /location \/AuditManagement\/{/{found=1;next} found && NF" "$CONF_FILE")

Comment: @ramesh.metta, No in `awk` you should use only `awk '...'` a single `'` quote only. To use SHELL variables in `awk` try something like `awk -v var="$SHELL_VARIABLE"  `your awk code here.....'  file` etc

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 : let me try and come back.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure you can accomplish what you want using grep by itself, but you can use the `sed` and `grep` commands together to get your desired output.

```
sed -n '/dev {/,/}/p' src_file
```

will give you the following output:

```
location /dev {
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_read_timeout 5m;
  proxy_send_timeout 5m;
  proxy_pass http://xyz.9202.com;

           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }
```

And if you want to remove the `dev {` and `}` lines, you can combine the sed command with grep -v like this:

```
sed -n '/dev {/,/}/p' src_file | grep -v "}" | grep -v "{"
```

which will give you the output that you desire:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_read_timeout 5m;
proxy_send_timeout 5m;
proxy_pass http://xyz.9202.com;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
```

Comment: FWIW, you can combine the two `grep`s into a single `grep -v '[{}]'`.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: i edited my question with things i tried.i tried various things since morning. since its a one liner, i just i didn't add it to my question.i still need to solve a major logic and what  i asked was a one liner pattern help. There will be non-unix people too who just quickly come to see the help to this great portal.

Comment: @ramesh.metta, Thanks for adding efforts, wrong or right doesn't  matter we only encourage people to add their efforts, I will add mine version too now :) cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Trying to parse block-based files with line-based tools is a dicey proposition with no guarantees. Most solutions will fail if there's another `{`...`}` block nested within the outer `location` block (by stopping after the first `}` instead of the matching one). That may not be an issue with your particular file, but this solution would handle it correctly:

```
awk '(inside && /{/)  { inside++ };
     (inside && /}/)  { --inside; if (!inside) { exit } };
     (inside) {print};
     /location \/dev[ \/{]/ { inside=1; }' src_file
```

There are still plenty of ways to break this, though. An actual parser library designed for (or configurable for) the syntax in question will give you more reliable results if this is going to be more than a one-off job.

Explanation: the design of this program uses a state variable called `inside` that, if nonzero, means the current line being processed is inside the stanza. Every new open-brace `{` causes the value to increase, while every close-brace `}` causes it to decrease. So once it hits zero after having been nonzero, we know we're done with the target stanza and can exit.

The stanzas are processed in order, so that order is very important. The very last stanza looks for the starting `location` line and sets our state variable to 1; if that stanza were first, then the starting `location` line would itself be printed by the subsequent stanzas. But as it is, the printing doesn't take effect until the next line of the file.

So: if we are inside the stanza and see another `{`, increment `inside`.
if we are inside the stanza and see a `}`, decrement `inside`. If it's now zero, that means we're done, so exit.
If we are inside (whether or not we just saw a { or }, as long as we didn't exit), then print the current line.
If we see `location /dev` ... followed by either a space, a slash, or a curly brace, so a different location that just starts with `/dev` won't match ... set `inside` to 1 indicating we should start printing with the next line.

Note that as written, the program assumes that the opening `{` for the whole stanza is on the same line as the `location` directive itself. If the the brace is on the next line instead, the nesting logic will mean it will print the whole file from that point. That's just an example of the fragility of this sort of approach.

Comment: i like this one as i have more complicated sub sections with many braces. this is working but if i have one more stanza with /dev2 , its displaying the other section too.

Comment: Updated to be more specific.

Comment: Hi.i'm trying to tweak the above awk statement to look for below : location /AuditManagement/ { . does the above will choke if there's / character ? i'm not seeing any result. no errors

Comment: The `/` terminates the regular expression match if you don't put a \ in front of it as in the example. The characters between `[`...`]` are options, so the above code matches "location /dev " with a space after /dev, "location /dev/" with a slash, or "location /dev{" with a curly brace. So if you replace `dev` with `AuditManagement` and leave the rest the same that should meet your requirement.

Comment: i thought so as u explained for [..] . but its not working or may be i'm doing some mistake. i have two /Audit and /AuditManagement/. script is able to find the /Audit but not `/AuditManagement/`.

Comment: seems its not working at my end. i got response for Audit. its empty when i use AuditManagement.  this is the string in source file:  `location /AuditManagement/ { `

Comment: Then `/location \/AuditManagement[ \/{]/` should match it.

Comment: This is returning empty.  `[user@xxxxx test]$ awk '(inside && /{/)  { inside++ };
     (inside && /}/)  { --inside; if (!inside) { exit } };
     (inside) {print};
     /location \/AuditManagement[ \/{]/ { inside=1; }'   mi.conf`

Comment: This one worked now. I removed extra space between location and /Auditmanagement. then i got the result back. Thanks much for help.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^\s*location .*{$/h;/^\s*$\|[{}]/b;G;/location \/dev/P' file
```

Make a copy of every line beginning `location` and ending with a `{`. Append the current copy to each line and if the double line contains `location /dev` print only the first of them.

N.B. Empty lines and lines containing `{` and `}` can be deleted beforehand.